# How to save tranasction id and do online refund for redirect based payment module in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions, payment-methods

I have made a redirect based payment module in magento 1. I am not doing capture in model file. With all details i am redirecting user to payment gateway and after payment user is getting back to site.

I am saving orders detail on overriding `OnepageController` and `successAction`.

My question is i want to add refund method in this module so admin can do online refund from Magento admin. But only Offline Refund is showing there not online refund. I think this is happening because transaction id is not saving in `sales_payment_transaction` tables but for this i do this code

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($lastOrderIds);
$payment = $orders->getPayment();
$hpp_obj->setTransactionId($transId);
$payment->setParentTransactionId($transId);
$payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
```

But it is not doing anything.
How to do this?